# PHP parse on page only if defined

Tags: php

I'm trying to define values for certain meta tags on pages of my website, however, I don't necessarily want to define them on every single page.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] != '/index.html'): ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page_info; ?>"/> }
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see, I have that set to parse on every page but index.html, however, I also want to create the following condition:

Will only parse if $page_info is defined, if not it will not parse anything at all in the `php if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for the `isset()` function?

```
<?php if ( isset( $page_info ) && $php_info ): ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $page_info; ?>"/> }
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Check out the docs for some more info on `isset()`.](http://php.net/isset)

> **`isset`** — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

The conditional expression I'm using here checks to see that a variable called `$page_info` exists **and** that it is not a "falsy" value. A falsy value is anything that, when converted to a [boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) could be considered a false value such as (taken from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)):

- the boolean FALSE itself
- the integer 0 (zero)
- the float 0.0 (zero)
- the empty string, and the string "0"
- an array with zero elements
- an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
- the special type NULL (including unset variables)
- SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
- Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource).

---

One other suggestion I can make is to not explicitly test for the page you want to exclude. Rather build an array of all the pages you want to exclude and then use an `in_array()` call to detect if it is in the list:

```
$exclude_url = array(
  '/index.html',
  '/about.html'
  '/faq.html'
);

if ( !in_array( $_SERVER[ 'SCRIPT_NAME' ], $exclude_url ) ){
  // page should NOT be excluded!
}
```

Comment: That's perfect. Actually solved a few other problems as well. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question? When using isset in the way specified where it parses the content only if the variable is defined, is there a way to add an additional exception inside the isset, where if it's not set, it'll parse a different specified variable?

Comment: Not something built-in... But you could easily do this by splitting the `if` statement into two statements with an `else` clause...